# Using arcpy.mapping to make changes to an open mxd

Tags: arcpy, mxd

I want to use arcpy.mapping to make some changes to a mxd.  I am using the Spyder environment for python.  To change the title I can use the following code:

```
import arcpy

myMap = r'C:\path_to_mxd\myfile.mxd'
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(myMap)
mxd.relativePaths = True
mxd.title = 'Title'
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
```

I can't execute `mxd.save()` on an open mxd file though.  Is there a way to make changes to an open file and view any code I execute on the fly?

Comment: You seem to be missing mxd.save().

Comment: saving it shouldn't affect the refresh, I should still see a change in arcmap without saving

Comment: Not if you are running your code from an IDE rather than through ArcMap. It sounds like you are doing the former. If not, can you [edit] your question to provide more details about how you are running your code, please?

Comment: ok, yes you are correct i am using an IDE.  adding `mxd.save()` returns `IOError: MapDocObject: unable to save. Check to make sure you have write access to the specified file and that there is enough space on the storage device to hold your document`.  I have access and plenty of space.

Comment: I got that error because the file was open in arcmap.  Is there a way to make changes and view them in a mxd that is open?

Comment: Your question seems to be changing so now, while there are no answers, is the time to heavily revise it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot save an open MXD from a python IDE external to ArcGIS.

You can, however, make changes to and save an MXD using Python from ArcMap itself.  Open the [python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm) (or you can attach to a [script tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/creating-tools/adding-a-script-tool.htm) if you prefer) and run your python from inside the open MXD.  You can display the python window from the menus Geoprocessing > Python Window.

You need to indicate to arcpy that you are looking at the open MXD by using `arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")`

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
mxd.relativePaths = True
mxd.title = 'Title'
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

The arcpy.mapping module was not designed to be used for the use case that you describe.  A relevant [post by Esri staff member Jeff Barrette at GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/19950) says this better than I can:

> Arcpy.mapping was designed for automating map documents (mxds) and
>   layer files (lyrs), not the ArcMap application.
>
> The functionality you are requesting is crossing into the realm of
>   desktop customization and that is what ArcObjects is for.