# Apply Symbology from Layer Not Working in Script

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, symbology, error-000732, layer-file

I am working on applying symbology to multiple layers from lyr files for multiple MXDs within the IDE. I have been able to access the MXDs and iterate through and change the definition of "mxd". I am receiving the following error, however, when the `ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management` process is run:

```
ERROR 000732: Input Layer: Dataset FCname does not exist or is not supported
```

My script is as follows:

```
# the MXDs to change, accessed and processed individually as 'i' is script not shown
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\Path\to\mxd\doc.mxd')
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if lyr.name == 'FCname':
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(
            in_layer="FCname",
            in_symbology_layer="C:\Path\to\lyrs\FCname.lyr")
```

I have repeated the same `ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management` tool within ArcMap successfully. Any ideas on why this process is not succeeding within my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to execute your code in **Standalone**.So you can't use input layer name, just use **layer** without any properties like name,... . 
save your mxd after the symbology changes. You can save the current mxd or save to another mxd file (Save a Copy).

```
# the MXDs to change, accessed and processed individually as 'i' is script not shown
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\Path\to\mxd\doc.mxd')
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"FCname"):
        arcpy.ApplySymbologyFromLayer_management(lyr,r"C:\Path\to\lyrs\FCname.lyr")
        mxd.saveACopy("C:/MychangeSymbology.mxd")
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I used the term IDE because I saw it [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227040/using-arcpy-mapping-to-make-changes-to-an-open-mxd) and thought it applied. Does it not? Would question be improved by changing IDE to Standalone?

Comment: IDE and standalone words are keywords you can use their to improve your question and help others